# Proftpd server: Server does not support non-ASCII characters

Tags: proftpd

I have moved my FTP (running proftpd) server from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 server and now there is a problem when connecting to it. In connection log there is a line that says:

```
"Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters."
```

and all files and folders that have non-ASCII characters cannot be downloaded.

I can fix this client-site by setting my FTP client (FileZilla for example) to explicitly use UTF-8 but the problem will still be there for others who connect to the FTP.

```
proftpd-basic/focal,now 1.3.6c-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
proftpd-doc/focal,now 1.3.6c-2 all [installed,automatic]
proftpd-mod-mysql/focal,now 1.3.6c-2 amd64 [installed]
```

Does anyone know what may be that cause for this error and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution to this problem!

```
MultilineRFC2228 off
```

bellow is part of the documentation about mod_core:

> Question: When I connect to ProFTPD using FileZilla, I see FileZilla
> log the following warning:
>
> Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters. even though I
> used the --enable-nls build option, and my ProFTPD supports UTF8. What
> is wrong?
>
> Answer: FileZilla parses the FEAT response to determine whether the
> FTP server supports the UTF-8 encoding. However, the format of the
> FEAT response can confuse FileZilla's detection code. For example, if
> your proftpd.conf uses:
>
> MultilineRFC2228 on
>
> this causes ProFTPD's FEAT response format to be different than
> FileZilla expects, which can lead to the above "does not support
> non-ASCII characters" message.
>
> The solution is to use:
>
> MultilineRFC2228 off
>
> in your proftpd.conf (or simply remove that directive entirely).

Answer (score 0):

This means the server only supports sftp and you are trying to use plaintext ftp.
Use sftp instead .
For example in Filezilla the host would be  sftp://<servername.com>